# How to solve gaps in continuity sequence with recursion?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 X  Y
-------
 A  1
 B  5
 C  9
```

I have a result set like the above data and want to achieve the value of X for the previous record to the records corresponding to the gaps in Y which is basically something that looks like below data. What are the different ways to achieve this?

```
X   Y
-------
 A  1
 A  2
 A  3
 A  4
 B  5
 B  6
 B  7
 B  8
 C  9
```

Comment: SQL cannot generate content that does not come out of the table that is queried, apart from constants. You probably have to generate the intermediate records outside your SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @tbl table
(
    X   char,
    Y   int
)

insert into @tbl select 'A', 1
insert into @tbl select 'B', 5
insert into @tbl select 'C', 9

-- Query 1 : recursive CTE 
; with 
cte as
(
    select  rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Y), X, Y
    from    @tbl
),
rcte as
(
    select  rn, X, Y 
    from    cte 
    where   rn  = 1

    union all

    select  rn  = case when r.Y + 1 < c.Y then r.rn else c.rn end, 
        X   = case when r.Y + 1 < c.Y then r.X else c.X end, 
        Y   = case when r.Y + 1 < c.Y then r.Y + 1 else c.Y end
    from    rcte r
        inner join cte c    on  r.rn = c.rn - 1
)
select  *
from    rcte

-- Query 2 : tally table method. Required SQL Server 2012+

; with tally as
(
    select  n = 1
    union all
    select  n = n + 1
    from    tally
    where   n <= 100
),
cte as
(   select  *, next_Y = isnull(LEAD(Y) OVER (ORDER BY Y), Y + 1)
    from    @tbl t
)
select  c.X, n.n as Y
from    cte c
    cross join tally n
where   n.n >= c.Y
and n.n < c.next_Y
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple query, (assume @tbl is your table/result set)

```
WITH cte_test
AS
(
    SELECT t.X,t.Y,isnull((SELECT min(t1.Y) FROM @tbl t1 WHERE t1.X > t.X),t.Y) AS maxval FROM @tbl t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.X,c.Y+1,c.maxval FROM cte_test c
    INNER JOIN @tbl t ON c.X = t.X
    WHERE c.Y+1 < c.maxval
)
SELECT X,Y FROM cte_test ORDER BY 1,2
```